# How to get the let time from a jquery coutdown

Tags: jquery, countdown

I'm new in jquery and I set a countdown time. Below that it is a question and answers.I want get the left time when user choose the answer,how can I do that?Thanks
  PS：I searched and found something called curvyCorners which said to be easier to get the left time ,but I don't know that

```
$(function() {
    var newYear = new Date();
    newYear = new Date(newYear.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 1);

    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({
        until: +30,
        compact: true,
        format: 'MS'
    });

    $('#getNow').click(function() {
        var periods = $('#curvyCorners').countdown('getTimes');
        var text = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < periods.length; i++) {
            text += periods[i] + '' + $.countdown.regional[''].labels[i] + '';
        }

        $('#curPeriods').text(text);
    });

    $('#removeCountdown').toggle(function() {
            $(this).text('Re-attach');
            $('#defaultCountdown').countdown('destroy');
        },
        function () {
            $(this).text('Remove');
            $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({
                until: +30
            });
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Well, that largely depends upon how you're storing and managing the counter. Please post code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method:

```
$(selector).countdown('getTimes');
```

It will return a number[7] array which entries are years, months, weeks, days, hours, minutes and seconds.